# Html.ValidationSummary Twitter Bootstrap Modal not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

this section of code does not work.

```
        @if (ViewData.ModelState.Any(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()))
    {
    <div class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Validation Errors</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.ValidationSummary()
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    }
```

But this does/ You can't dismiss the alert but it pops up!

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.Any(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()))
{
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    <h4>Validation Errors</h4>
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
</div>
}
```

Im using exactly the same validation Razor code each time. & i'm not sure if i should be seeing things happen in the chrome developer toolkit or not.

EDIT:
Here is the complete page.

```
@using Project.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
Layout = "";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

</head>
 <body class="login-page">
             @if (ViewData.ModelState.Any(x => x.Value.Errors.Any()))
             {
                <div class="modal fade" id="ValidationSummaryModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span     aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Validation Errors</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @Html.ValidationSummary()
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-    dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save     changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div><!-- /.modal -->
    }
    <div class="login-box">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl },     FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="login-box-title red">
                @ViewBag.Title
            </div>
            <div class="login-box-content">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "Email" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password",    @type="password" })
                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in!">
                <div class="half">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                </div>
                <div class="half last">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Sign Up!", "Register")
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('#ValidationSummaryModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean does not work? the modal wont show by itself. If these blocks of code are at same view and "alert" shows up that means that modal is as well there in your DOM.

Comment: It's Showing up in the DOM, But still not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an id (#ValidationSummaryModal for example) if you have other modals in same view and on page load 
at a section below scripts add this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#ValidationSummaryModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. though it didn't work.  Ill update my question with the whole page so you can see the changes as you advised.

Comment: why you have  @section Scripts?

Comment: It was because i was rendering the page with a layout. Ive removed that section now to test. still no luck.

Comment: I even tried to connect the event up to a button but that didn't work either.